# Storing buffer into a variable

Tags: c++, winsock

I display my buffer like this:

```
void WINAPI MyUCPackets(char* unpkt, int packetlen, int iR, int arg)

cout << "[" << packetlen << "] ";
for ( int i = 0; i < packetlen; i++ ) {
printf( "%02x ", unsigned char (unpkt[i]) );
}
printf( "\n" );
```

Now I need to check if part of the buffer contains an specific value like:

```
if(unpkt[1] == 0xfb && unpkt[2] == 0x05 && unpkt[3]== 0x20)
{
    unpkt = dcpkt;
}
```

The output from the print:

```
6C FB 05 20 00
```

I need to check if the exact buffer was used except for the 1st byte because its random.

But It doesn't work. The condition doesn't get executed and I'm sure that unpkt1 is 0xfb and unpkt2 is 05 because the print of the buffer displays that value.

I tried to use `sprintf` to store the buffer as hex but it seems messy. any other idea?

`sprintf(buf2, "%02X", unpkt[1]);`

Comment: What is the output you see from the first snippet?  You know that arrays in C++ are zero-based, yes?

Comment: Do you mean to check `unpkt[0]` and `unpkt[1]`?

Comment: I updated my question. thanks. I don't need the `unpkt[0]` its random. I only need to check the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comparison against `0xfb` is likely failing (signed versus unsigned).  If `unpkt` is defined as `char`, then the statement might need to be:

```
if((unsigned char)unpkt[1] == 0xfb && (unsigned char)unpkt[2] == 0x05 && (unsigned char)unpkt[3]== 0x20)
{
    unpkt = dcpkt;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you are comparing two values, two sides should be both `signed` or both `unsigned`.
See this example:

```
char x = 0xFB;

if (x == 0xFB)
    printf("YES");
else
    printf("NO");
```

Output, ***we expect "YES" but we got "NO"***

> NO

---

The values you are displaying are different of values you are testing:

```
printf( "%02x ", unsigned char (unpkt[i]) );
```

Remove `unsigned char` casting, and then display values. I guess you will see different values.

Comment: void WINAPI MyUCPackets(char* unpkt, int packetlen, int iR, int arg)

Answer (score 1):

You stick to `printf` (a.k.a. C streams) or `cout` (C++ streams) and don't cross the streams, because it would be "bad, very bad" -- Ghostbusters I

Try using:

```
cout << "0x" << hex << (unsigned int) unpkt[i];
```